# How to use boost::bind correctly with a map of function pointers

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, bind, function-pointers

I am trying to achieve something like this but getting boost bind related errors

```
#include <map>
#include "boost/assign.hpp"
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>


struct myStruct_t
{
    int getInt () {return 1;};
};

int foo(  myStruct_t* m, std::string str)
{
    if(str == "A")
    {
        return m->getInt();
    }
    else if (str == "B")
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 3;
    }
}

typedef std::map<std::string, boost::function<int(myStruct_t*, std::string)> > Map_t;

Map_t myMap = boost::assign::map_list_of    ("Jake", boost::bind((&foo, _1), "A")
                                        ("Ken", boost::bind((&foo, _1), "B")
                                        ("Pete", boost::bind((&foo, _1), "C");



int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::string> myVal;
    myVal.push_back("Jake");
    myVal.push_back("Ken");
    myVal.push_back("Pete");

    myStruct_t myStruct;
    BOOST_FOREACH( const std::string& aStr, myVal)
    {
        Map_t::const_iterator iter = myMap.find(aStr);
        if(iter != myMap.end())
        {
            int myInt = (iter->second)(myStruct);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I am getting are

```
   In file included from /usr/local/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from prog.cc:6:
/usr/local/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::arg<1> >':
/usr/local/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1212:48:   instantiated from 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<const char*> > >'
prog.cc:32:81:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:75:37: error: no type named 'result_type' in 'struct boost::arg<1>'
prog.cc:34:82: error: expected ')' before ';' token
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:50:48: error: no match for call to '(const boost::function<int(myStruct_t*, std::basic_string<char>)>) (myStruct_t&)'
/usr/local/boost-1.60.0/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:765:17: note: candidate is: result_type boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::operator()(T0, T1) const [with R = int, T0 = myStruct_t*, T1 = std::basic_string<char>, result_type = int]
```

It seems I am puzzled the way boost::bind is used. Can someone please help me doing it correctly? Many Thanks.

Comment: You have an extra set of parentheses in `boost::bind((&foo, _1), "A")` and all the others. Remove them.

Comment: Also, the type of `Map` should be `boost::function<int(myStruct_t*)>`

Comment: Removed the extra parenthesis and changed the Map to  boost::function<int(myStruct_t*)>. Still getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function signature expected at the call site is int(myStruct*)

because of this line (I added the & to remove a logic error):

```
int myInt = (iter->second)(&myStruct);
```

in which case the declaration of the map should be:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, boost::function<int(myStruct_t*)> > Map_t;

Map_t myMap = boost::assign::map_list_of
("Jake", boost::bind(&foo, boost::placeholders::_1, std::string("A")))
("Ken", boost::bind(&foo, boost::placeholders::_1, std::string("B")))
("Pete", boost::bind(&foo, boost::placeholders::_1, std::string("C")));
```

And then you're good to go.

explanation:

boost[std]::bind returns a function object which is designed to accept only the parameters that are mentioned as placeholders in the `bind` expression.

This means that the function that is finally called will often have more arguments than the function object returned by `bind`

so in your case, `foo` has the following signature:

```
int foo(  myStruct_t* m, std::string str)
```

i.e. takes two arguments and returns an int.

However at the point of the call to `bind`:

```
boost::bind(&foo, boost::placeholders::_1, std::string("A"))
```

What we're saying is "capture the function `foo` and the second argument (a string). Return me a function object that requires one argument (`_1`) and forward that argument as the first argument to `foo` while passing the bound string as the second argument.

so given:

```
auto f = boost::bind(&foo, boost::placeholders::_1, std::string("A"));
```

`f` has the signature `int f(MyStruct*)`

and when called with

```
auto i = f(&mystruct);
```

it is equivalent to calling:

```
auto i = foo(&mystruct, std::string("A"));
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked well. I can understand one issue that the function was expecting a pointer and I was passing an object. But the function int foo(  myStruct_t* m, std::string str) expects two parameters myStruct_t and std::string. Then why do the  boost::function<int(myStruct_t*)> has only one parameter in the declaration?

Comment: @polapts updated with a longer explanation. Hope that's useful.

Comment: Excellet! Many Thanks.